# configure: error: gmp.h (GMP) is required

Tags: unix, gmp, gnucobol

when i try to install open-cobol i run ./configure then this error shows in the end:

```
configure: error: gmp.h (GMP) is required
```

then i do this:

```
sudo apt-get install  libgmp3-dev
```

but i got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
ant ant-optional junit junit4 kde-l10n-engb libasm3-java libclassworlds-java
libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-cli-java libcommons-collections3-java
libcommons-configuration-java libcommons-digester-java
libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-jexl-java libcommons-jxpath-java
libcommons-lang-java libcommons-net2-java libcommons-vfs-java libdoxia-java
libeasymock-java libganymed-ssh2-java libgoogle-collections-java
libhamcrest-java libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java libitext1-java
libjetty-java libjsch-java libjsoup-java libjsr305-java
libmaven-archiver-java libmaven-clean-plugin-java
libmaven-compiler-plugin-java libmaven-dependency-tree-java
libmaven-file-management-java libmaven-filtering-java
libmaven-install-plugin-java libmaven-jar-plugin-java
libmaven-resources-plugin-java libmaven-scm-java libmaven-shade-plugin-java
libmaven-shared-io-java libmaven2-core-java libmodello-java
libnetbeans-cvsclient-java libplexus-ant-factory-java
libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-build-api-java
libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java libplexus-compiler-api-java
libplexus-compiler-java libplexus-compiler-javac-java
libplexus-compiler-manager-java libplexus-container-default-java
libplexus-containers-java libplexus-digest-java libplexus-i18n-java
libplexus-interactivity-api-java libplexus-interpolation-java
libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils-java
libregexp-java libservlet2.5-java libslf4j-java libwagon-java libxbean-java
openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
libgmp-dev
Suggested packages:
libgmp10-doc libmpfr-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 358 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,551 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libgmp-dev amd64 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libgmp3-dev amd64 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gmp/libgmp-dev_5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gmp/libgmp3-dev_5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: You want to ask on an ubuntu forum, but you could try a different mirror or upgrade your distribution (this mirror doesn't seem to have raring packages?).

Comment: how can i move this question to ubuntu forum

Comment: I don't know, Askubuntu isn't listed when I try to flag the post for migration (so I didn't).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference.

```
sudo apt-get install open-cobol
```

This will fill in the dependencies, all tested against repo package versions.

Then snag a tarball and

```
./configure; make
```

It will make for a much smoother GnuCOBOL experience.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but I want to compile GNU COBOL from source.

Comment: After doing `apt-get install  libgmp3-dev` this error was gone. Now I'm getting *Berkeley DB db.h is missing*

Comment: @IonicăBizău look to libdb-dev

Comment: @IonicăBizău  And you may want to `svn up` on the tree, just added a new -j feature, so things can be scripted now.